# Portable PHP/Javascript plugin for binary JSON (or similar formats)?

Tags: javascript, php, json, bson

I've been looking for something like MongoDB's BSON or MessagePack, but portable. The server that hosts the project I need this for does not allow installations. Is there anything like them, that can be run off the bat in PHP and Javascript?
Python and Java are not allowed on the server, either.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Does your server application produce that BSON? Does it read it from another service (which)? Does your JavaScript need to parse it, or does it send it to your application, ...etc, etc.

Comment: The website is required to store and retrieve serialized data inside a compact format, using only PHP code or Javascript. More precisely, my PHP code needs to create the file, and Javascript would need to parse it. I'm using JSON for now, but the size is getting too big.

Comment: The JSON size is too big for PHP, for the transfer, or for JavaScript? What size are we talking about? Are you actually storing the file, or just sending it as response to the client? Are you using Ajax for loading the response data?

Comment: The JSON file is being sent as response to the client. The Javascript code directly accesses the file from the website (as it would an image) to read from it and print information to the webpage. The file is already 1.6 megabytes, and it's expected to get larger; PHP also needs to be able to write to it in a fashionable amount of time (i.e. <30s). The server is storing the file, but I won't expect it to exceed the maximum storage allowance. I'm not using Ajax at the moment, but albeit I'd like to implement it it won't be an actual solution to the problem.

Comment: Does the client need all the data all at once? Is lazy loading not an alternative? Sure, compression is a solution, but you'll soon hit the limits again when the data becomes 10x as large, so I think you need to look in another direction. What is the data? An image? Video? A table of numbers?

Comment: I'd love to implement long-term solutions like constructing the webpage beforehand, splitting up the files for lazy loading, caching, etc. but as for the moment, the quickest approach would be to change the format of the file, since any other solution would inevitably become a workaround without it. As it is now, PHP needs to first decode the file, then adding data, then re-encoding it, which is also a problem. The file is a table of integers, serialized by date and time, representing an archived record of a counter that updates once per minute.

Comment: But what do you display on the client? No human can digest 1.6 MB of integers (on one screen?) that change every minute, so are you displaying aggregated data? If so, you should really consider sending the aggregated data to the client and only that part of the detailed data that are actually visualised. If the user has controls to open up more details, then that should trigger a new server request to go and fetch that part, which should be possible to do very fast, given the volume will be relatively small.

Comment: The data is visualized in the form of a graph, which uses all the data plus more (averages, etc.) calculated on top of that. As I said, I could implement a server-side code that would generate a graph beforehand, but that's a long-term goal. It still would require smaller file sizes for it to be parsed quickly.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but if you have a single-line graph across a typical screen with, say 2000 pixels horizontally, there is no need to have more than 2000 integers for that line. If you show 3 lines, then that makes 6000 integers. Any meta data that users can get by (for example) hovering over a single data point can be fetched from the server in real-time. 6000 integers represent in a simple JSON array form some 60KB, so what is accounting for the rest of that 1.6 MB?

Comment: How do I know which integers to pick without accessing the whole file? It's like asking the CPU to fetch a single bit flag without accessing the whole byte. Again, constructing the data beforehand is further long-term optimization, I would still need better compression. The file is now of more or less one year worth of data. My old backup (~one month) is 468k.

Comment: Your data is in a flat file? What is the file type? I thought the problem was in the size of the JSON that your application generated from that data source, but now I get the impression you indicate there is a bottleneck for the server to read the data from a file? You don't have a database?

Comment: It's a JSON file. Creating a full-fledged database system just to store some integers makes no sense to me. The problem is in the size of the JSON, and I need a portable PHP/Javascript plugin to encode it in binary. Do you know of any such plugin?

Comment: So do I understand you don't have a server application? If so, what is it doing, if you already have the JSON file? I thought to understand your PHP *created* the JSON? Then where is the JSON coming from? I am not going to provide a solution of which I think it implements the wrong approach.

Comment: In that case, I appreciate the will to help, but that's not what I need. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [rybakit/msgpack.php](https://github.com/rybakit/msgpack.php), it implements the MessagePack format in pure PHP, no extensions are needed.